# I cannot make a new directory in this file path in my batch file?

Tags: batch-file, mkdir

I am doing a project that lets you select a file, then it moves it to a certain place. But I am having a problem because I want to to check for a certain folder and if that is no then it creates one.
At the moment I have.

```
if exist C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\main folder\Dropzone goto next

if not exist C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\main foler\Dropzone
mkdir C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\main folder\Dropzone

:next
```

But I am having trouble, I understand that I you need '^' in between the spaces or something but I have tried that and it has not worked.

Has anyone got any suggestions? Thanks,

Comment: But I am not copying? I need to create a folder called 'Dropzone' in mainfolder. Or can I use copy?

Comment: Try my answer: it uses double quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if not exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\main foler\Dropzone" (
mkdir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\main folder\Dropzone"
)
:next
```

You need the double quotes.

Mona

Comment: Ahh, ok. But will I need " for the 'if exist' as well?

Comment: You don't need the `if exist` statement at all. If you think about it, if the file **does** exist, then the `mkdir` command will be skipped and you will continue to the `:next`. If you are adamant about keeping your `if exist` statement than yes. Consider it a rule in batch: ***`If it has spaces: Double Quote it`***

Comment: Ahh ok, thank you very much. It is working now. If it was not for you I would of got nowhere.

Comment: @Bittenfleax can you please make this correct if it was helpful.

Comment: Ok, this is my first post, how do I do that?

Comment: @Bittenfleax Next to my answer there should be a tick mark. Wait.. You found it Nice work.

Comment: @Bittenfleax If you want more info on batch, feel free to ask. Also- never underestimate the help command. And remember to understand ANY command simply type `commandname /?` and it will give you basic info in cmd.